# Android app run custom executable - permission denied

Tags: java, android

I am working on a project where I have to port an C/C++ application to Android. I made a successful build with CMake and the android toolchain from https://github.com/taka-no-me/android-cmake

After the build I pushed the executables to an Android emulator and called them in the shell (ADB shell). These things are working well. Currently I am working on an Android application where I want to call the copied executables from Java. 
The files are located under /data/local/myfolder and do have following permission

```
 -rwxrwxrwx root     root           37 2016-08-02 06:30 rexx
```

My question is if it possible to run my executables from Java code? I tried following source:

```
private void runSingleCommand(){
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("rexx", null, new File("/data/local/myfolder/")); //Permission denied exception

        InputStreamReader reader = new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream());
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(reader);
        int numRead;
        char[] buffer = new char[5000];
        StringBuffer commandOutput = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numRead = bufferedReader.read(buffer)) > 0) {
            commandOutput.append(buffer, 0, numRead);
        }
        bufferedReader.close();
        process.waitFor();

        System.out.println("--> Output: "+commandOutput.toString());

    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }

}
```

Executing this code I get following Exception

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [rexx.sh] Working Directory: /data/local/oorexx Environment: null
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.exec.RexxExecuter.runSingleCommand(RexxExecuter.java:146)
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.exec.RexxExecuter.runTheRexxImage(RexxExecuter.java:24)
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41)
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231)
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148)
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error running exec(). Command: [rexx.sh] Working Directory: /data/local/oorexx Environment: null
     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:211)
     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173)
     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246)
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.exec.RexxExecuter.runSingleCommand(RexxExecuter.java:127)
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.exec.RexxExecuter.runTheRexxImage(RexxExecuter.java:24) 
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785) 
     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601) 
     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
  Caused by: java.io.IOException: Permission denied
     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(Native Method)
     at java.lang.ProcessManager.exec(ProcessManager.java:209)
     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:173) 
     at java.lang.Runtime.exec(Runtime.java:246) 
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.exec.RexxExecuter.runSingleCommand(RexxExecuter.java:127) 
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.exec.RexxExecuter.runTheRexxImage(RexxExecuter.java:24) 
     at org.oorexx.oorexxforandroid.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:41) 
     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5231) 
     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2148) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2233) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:135) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1196) 
     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136) 
     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5001) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
```

I was searching a lot, but I did not found a clear answer if (and how) it is possible to run a executable from Java without root user.

Comment: why not using ndk / jni?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Reason to not use JNI is that i do not really have access to the source of the c++ project. Therefore I cannot add functions for jni support. As I understand I have to implement additional functions to call the libraries via jni or am I wrong?

Comment: _"i do not really have access to the source of the c++ project"_. How are you porting something that you don't have the source code for?

Comment: so how did you build it with cmake? yes, you should add just one "glue" method, that's all

Comment: I have access to the source, but if possible only as "reader", my purpose was it to adapt only the CMakeLists.txt file. That is the reason why I was asking if it is possible to call an executable via shell and not with jni.

Comment: use jni and if you dont want to modify / analize the sources just call its `main(int argc, char* argv[])` function

Comment: Ok, thank you, i will try it

Comment: @pskink maybe you can give me a hint how to call the main (my main looks like this `int main (int argc, char **argv)`) without changing the source of the shared library. Do you have some example?

Comment: i dont have any, see official samples: https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ndk, maybe you will find something